# Auto sort Excel table which is updated via DDE

Tags: excel, dde, vba

I want to Auto sort a table in which the data is updated via DDE. I am using a macro similar to this for auto update, but this doesnt work for data updates done via DDE.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), _
  Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
  OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the
**Worksheet_Calculate()** event which is the simplest but it will not give you any info about what who or where. But it will get triggered when you get DDE data

But if you need more you can use the event SetLinkOnData

```
Sub Workbook_Open() 
 ActiveWorkbook.SetLinkOnData  "ProgramName|DocumentName!cellField",  "myMacroName" 
End Sub
```

It's convultet to set up but you can look at the documentation [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-link-using-dynamic-data-exchange-dde-HP003066210.aspx)

Comment: I am new to EXCEL macro's and VB can you please tell me how I can incorporate this in my EXCEL Macro